# Clear Ng autocomplete after selection

Tags: angular, user-interface, angular-material, autocomplete, angular14

The problem I'm having is the behaviour I need is, when an option is selected from the autocomplete input, it should add element to data array (which it does) and it should also clear the autocomplete input, so I can then select another option.(which it doesnt).This is for ng autocomplete not for material auto complete. A code working example where i can encounter this issue:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-autocomplete?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

I tried to search for property but couldnt find it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for multiple selection in `ng-autocomplete` ( even if you clear the previous selection from search, only one value can get stored for that autocomplete! ) when I checked the [sourcecode](https://github.com/gmerabishvili/angular-ng-autocomplete/blob/master/projects/autocomplete-lib/src/lib/autocomplete.component.ts), You can either raise a feature request on their [github page](https://github.com/gmerabishvili/angular-ng-autocomplete) or try an alternative

- [primeng autocomplete multiple support](https://primeng.org/autocomplete#multiple)
- [angular material select with multiple selection](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview)